# How to fix 'Incorrect syntax near '13' in SQL query

Tags: sql

When I am executing a query with datetime datatype in sql server, its displaying the error as
"Incorrect syntax near '13'".

When I excecuted the below code, it displayed the error as

> "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near '13'."

```
create table OverDraftLog
(
    AccountID               int primary key not null,
    OverDraftDate               datetime,
    OverDraftAmount             money,
    OverDraftTransaction                varchar(30)
);

insert into OverDraftLog(AccountID,OverDraftDate,OverDraftAmount,OverDraftTransaction)
values
    (101,2018-12-30 13:23:44,25,'Overdraft Fee'),
    (102,2019-01-15 11:04:17,25,'Overdraft Fee'),
    (103,2018-10-20 12:15:36,30,'Overdraft Fee'),
    (104,2019-02-10 14:32:14,20,'Overdraft Fee'),
    (105,2018-12-05 16:43:57,20,'Overdraft Fee');
```

I expect to be error free code.

Comment: Date constants need to be in single quotes.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the datetime value inside quotes, such as `'2018-12-30 13:23:44'`